# MVC Mini Profiler with Entity Framework: How to Get Connection

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I would like to use MVC Mini Profiler for Entity Framework Connection. The way I did it is like this:

```
public static XXXXX.DAL.BO.XXXXXEntities GetEntityConnection()
    {
        var conn = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(new EntityConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXXXXEntities"].ConnectionString));
        return ObjectContextUtils.CreateObjectContext<XXXXX.DAL.BO.XXXXXEntities>(conn);
    }
```

So the following line is to get the Context for the rest of the code:

```
XXXXX.DAL.BO.XXXXXEntities ctx = GetEntityConnection();
```

When I attempted to view this site on a browser, however, the WebDev.WebServer40.exe crashed.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks heaps.

P.S.
Previously it was

```
XXXXX.DAL.BO.XXXXXEntities ctx = new XXXXX.DAL.BO.XXXXXEntities();
```

and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use the v3.0.10 nuget for EF6, then all you need to do to hook up Entity Framework is

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
}
```

Using EF 5 or earlier (with the corresponding nuget package) would require you to generate an `EFProfiledDbConnection` as Anirudh wrote in his answer:

```
var conn =  new EFProfiledDbConnection(GetConnection(), MiniProfiler.Current);
return ObjectContextUtils.CreateObjectContext<MyModel>(conn);
```

Comment: Where does `GetConnection()` method come from?

Answer (score 0):

try initialising your connection to :

```
connection = new EFProfiledDbConnection( new EntityConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXXXXEntities"].ConnectionString),
                        MiniProfiler.Current);
```

works for me.